# Python NumPy Convert Columns to Rows

Tags: python, numpy

Python 2.7.10 and NumPy. I have a matrix like this:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
[ 3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8]
[ 9 10 11]]

[[12 13 14]
[15 16 17]
[18 19 20]
[21 22 23]]

[[24 25 26]
[27 28 29]
[30 31 32]
[33 34 35]]

[[36 37 38]
[39 40 41]
[42 43 44]
[45 46 47]]]
```

Note: The real matrix will have real data, and not consecutive numbers.

I need to rotate, flip, or something (I have tried them all) so as to end up with this:

```
[[[ 2 5 8 11]
[ 1 4 7 10]
[ 0 3 6 9]

[[14 17 20 23]
[13 16 19 22]
[12 15 18 21]

[[26 29 32 35]
[25 28 31 34]
[24 27 30 33]

[[38 41 44 47]
[37 40 43 46]
[36 39 42 45]]]
```

Basically, I need the entire columns of the matrix to become the rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip the positions of columns with `[:,:,::-1]` and use [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to swap rows with columns -

```
In [25]: A
Out[25]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]]])

In [26]: A[:,:,::-1].transpose(0,2,1)
Out[26]: 
array([[[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
        [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [ 0,  3,  6,  9]],

       [[14, 17, 20, 23],
        [13, 16, 19, 22],
        [12, 15, 18, 21]],

       [[26, 29, 32, 35],
        [25, 28, 31, 34],
        [24, 27, 30, 33]]])
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I did try both slicing and transpose, but just not the two together.

Comment: I tested this vs the other approach (fliplr(a).transpose(0,2,1), and the f(f(f(a).T).T).transpose(0,2,1), and found that this took 5.3; the fliplr took 8.3, and the last one took 13.6 seconds using the timeit module.

Comment: @gbronner Nice! Well I guess it would be interesting to test out `A[:,:,::-1].swapaxes(1,2)` too!

Comment: @Divakar  `swapaxes` seemed to be indistinguishable from `transpose(0,2,1)`.

Comment: @gbronner Yes, functionally they are same!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way to do it:

```
a=numpy.arange(48).reshape((4,4,3)
numpy.fliplr(a.swapaxes(1,2))
#or you could do
numpy.fliplr(a.transpose(0,2,1))
```

From what I can tell, `flipud` flips the *last* dimension, while `fliplr` flips the second to last dimension.  In three dimensions, the last dimension is Z, while the second to last dimension is Y.  Hence transposing the data, and flipping the Y dimension works.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

For each 2d subarray in your super-array you can apply the numpy function:

`np.rot90()` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html

so:

```
import numpy as np

array= np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
[ 3,  4,  5],
[ 6,  7,  8],
[ 9, 10, 11]],

[[12, 13, 14],
[15, 16, 17],
[18, 19, 20],
[21, 22, 23]],

[[24, 25, 26],
[27, 28, 29],
[30, 31, 32],
[33, 34, 35]],

[[36, 37, 38],
[39, 40, 41],
[42, 43, 44],
[45, 46, 47]]])

desired_output = np.array([np.rot90(sub_array) for sub_array in array])
```

Answer (score 0):

`transpose` and `flipud` are what you are looking for; the `swapaxes` can also function as transpose
Note that transpose has a version that operates on multiple dimensions.

There may be a simpler expression for this, but this has the advantage of not using elaborate indexing.  Example, done in Python 2.7.3 with numpy

```
f=numpy.flipud
a=numpy.arange(48).reshape((4,4,3))
result=f(f(f(a).T).T).transpose(0,2,1)

In [2]: a=numpy.arange(48).reshape((4,4,3))
Out[3]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 11]],

   [[12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17],
    [18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23]],

   [[24, 25, 26],
    [27, 28, 29],
    [30, 31, 32],
    [33, 34, 35]],

   [[36, 37, 38],
    [39, 40, 41],
    [42, 43, 44],
    [45, 46, 47]]])
In [5]: f(f(f(a).T).T).transpose(0,2,1)
Out[5]:
array([[[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
    [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
    [ 0,  3,  6,  9]],

   [[14, 17, 20, 23],
    [13, 16, 19, 22],
    [12, 15, 18, 21]],

   [[26, 29, 32, 35],
    [25, 28, 31, 34],
    [24, 27, 30, 33]],

   [[38, 41, 44, 47],
    [37, 40, 43, 46],
    [36, 39, 42, 45]]])
```

.

Comment: Did not work for me. However, I do appreciate the response.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it transposes the *whole* array.

Comment: Actually, it does work. It is just very ugly.  I came up with a simpler version that is clearer.  To be perfectly honest, the flipud/fliplr statements seem like they could be replaced with a more generic flip by axis, which would be more obvious as one goes from 2 to 3 dimensions.